# Dynamically set highcharts endrow option based on user input

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to dynamically set the endrow object based on user input in highcharts.  A user would select from a list control between the values 5, 10, 25 and all and I would like to pass that value to the data.endrow property.  Thoughts?

```
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        startRow: 0,
        endRow: <userinput>
        endColumn: 1,
        firstRowAsNames: false
    },
```

Comment: Why not load it all and dynamically set the extremes of the x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your chart after you will click on submit button. You can check selected value inside your list and pass it to chart options:

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    var dropMenu = $('#drop'),
      selectedIndex = dropMenu[0].options.selectedIndex,
      stringVal = $(dropMenu)[0].options[selectedIndex].value,
      value = parseInt(stringVal);
    if (stringVal === 'All') {
      var lines = document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML.split('\n');
      value = lines.length - 1;
    }
});
```

Then you can make a chart with new endRow parameter:

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Global temperature change'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Data module: Show only last 20 years by limiting start row.'
    },
    data: {
      csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
      startRow: 1,
      endRow: value,
      endColumn: 1,
      firstRowAsNames: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Annual mean'
    }]
  });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/jpko073c/3/